# Name resolution failure with Spring Gateway and Eureka

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, gateway

Good day,

At this moment I am working on a very simple gateway that (for now) only needs to redirect incoming HTTP POST and GET requests.

**THE SETUP:**

- The Eureka Server: the location where my Spring Boot microservices are registered;
- The Spring Gateway: maps all incoming HTTP POST and GET requests and routes them to the proper microservice;
- The Spring Boot microservices: doing just some thingies as requested :)

Note: I'm kinda new to this gateway stuff, just you know :).

The microservice is registered fine with the Eureka server. Its webbased GUI shows me that the instance "MY-MICRO-SERVICE" is registered with the Eureka server. Other (Spring Boot) services can use that name ("MY-MICRO-SERVICE") without issues, so for them it works fine. Just this gateway can't handle the instance name; it seems it only accepts IP addresses (which I just want to prevent, as the microservice can change from servers and therefor their IP address). And the Eureka server is not configured to only allow/use IP addresses.

---

**THE ISSUE:**

All runs smooth when the Gateway has a route that holds an IP address of the microservice. But what I want is to let the Gateway resolve the service ID from the Eureka server. And if I do that, it throws me a `java.net.UnknownHostException: MY-MICRO-SERVICE: Temporary failure in name resoultion`.

---

**THE QUESTION:**

Now why can't I use the name of the Spring application "MY-MICRO-SERVICE" (being the registered Spring Boot microservice) in the Spring Gateway (while that construction works fine when used in other microservices)? Can't a Yaml config file handle such instance names, just only IP addresses?

---

**THE DETAILS**

The gateway is mostly configured via a yaml config file. There is only one simple Java class that kicks off the gateway application. The routing is all set in the yaml config file.

***The Spring Gateway application class***

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class MyGatewayApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyGatewayApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

***The Gateway Yaml configuration file (application.yml)***

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          lowerCaseServiceId: true
          enabled: true
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedMethods:
              - GET
              - POST
      routes:
        - id: my_route
          uri: http://MY-MICRO-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/test/**
server:
  port: 8999

info:
  app:
    properties: dev
```

***The Error***

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: MY-MICRO-SERVICE: Temporary failure in name resolution
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1248) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:146) ~[netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
...
```

Comment: Another note: I also added a Bean - LoadBalanced public WebClient.Builder method (which returns a WebClient.builder()). The main method as described above is no longer annotated with LoadBalancer (as it is no bean).
But still the same issue remains.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue has been fixed.

I changed the "http" to "lb" protocol and that fixed my issue. To my understanding, "lb" stands for LoadBalancing. I have no loadbalancer active on my local machine, but anyway: this works.

```
   - POST
      routes:
        - id: my_route
          uri: lb://MY-MICRO-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/test/**
```

Comment: replacing *http or https with lb* doesn't works with me